# Namespace has no exported member or Module has no exported member with circular dependencies in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I swear at one point this configuration was working for me, circular dependencies and all, but now after a refactoring, it isn't working. I basically have a folder like this (but with about a hundred files):

```
./index.ts
./code/index.ts
./code/something/else.ts
./code/another/thing.ts
./code/more/pieces.ts
```

I have in my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "~": ["./index.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

In my `index.js` I have:

```
import * as code from './code.js'

export default code
```

In the code/index.js I have:

```
export * from './something/else.js'
export * from './another/thing.js'
...
```

Then in each of those files, I do:

```
import code from '~'
```

Hence, circular dependencies.

This was working fine at some point. I would like to know if maybe this is pressing VSCode to its limits and it can't compute or something, because I get two errors *only for some of the imports*!

> Module '"~"' has no exported member 'Foo'.

When doing:

```
import { Foo } from '~'
```

And:

> Namespace '[path]' has no exported member 'Foo'

When doing:

```
import code from '~'

type X = { foo: code.Foo }
```

But here's the thing, look at this, *some* of the types are importing (`SiteFork`), but some are not (`Riff`):

[image]

There are no errors in any of my TS files, I am not sure why this isn't working. Any ideas how to fix, or if it's a VSCode bug?

Comment: This occurs because you have exported the result of a namespace import as a single object. While the Syntax for import looks deceptively like object destructuring, it has entirely different semantics.

Comment: @AluanHaddad mind elaborating, I don't know what you mean or how that helps in this situation.

Comment: `from './code.js'` looks wrong, given that you don't have a *code.js* file. Maybe you meant `from './code'` to refer to the *code* **folder** (and the *code/index.js* file in it)?

Comment: Also @AluanHaddad is correct, your `import { Foo } from '~'` cannot work since `export default code` is only a default export, your module has no named exports. You'll need to use `code.Foo` if there's such an export in the namespace object.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
import * as code from './code.js'
export default code
```

but it seems that you try to use it as

```
export * from './code/index.js'
import * as code from './code/index.js'
export default code
//////////////
// elsewhere:
import code, { Foo } from '~'
```

or

```
export * from './code/index.js'
//////////////
// elsewhere:
import * as code from '~'
import { Foo } from '~'
```